# Can't get my script (jquery) to insert text from frame 1 into textarea in frame 2.

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, dynamic-linking, frames

I have been trying to get this going without success--performed advanced search unsuccessfully.  Current setup is as follows:   I cannot figure out how to link the frames together so when I click the list in the first frame, the text is inserted and shows up in the second frame text area.  I know there must be an easier way to do this that I am missing.  Thank you!

```
         index.html (frameset)
              |
              |
            /   \
           /     \
     group_a.html    group_b.html



**index.html**
<html>
<frameset cols="60%,40%" FRAMEBORDER=NO FRAMESPACING=0 BORDER=0>>
  <frame src="group_a.html">
  <frame src="group_b.html">
</frameset>
</html>

group_a.html
</style>
<style>
    li:hover {
        cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; background-color:#66CCFF
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery221min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
        $('#alltext').append($(this).text());

        $("a").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
    });
    function redirectPage() {
        top.frames["group_b.html"].location = linkLocation;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li>Text choice 1</li>
    <li>Text choice 2</li>
    <li>Text choice 3</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>

 group_b.html
 <html>
  <body>

    <form>
      <textarea name="alltext" id="alltext" cols="60" rows="30">      </textarea>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frame1 does not have access to the DOM of frame2. That means you can't manipulate the textarea using jQuery as you expect. instead, use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send a message between frames, and then in the second frame set up a listener for that message. when you receive it, set the text accordingly. Something like:

**Frame 1**

```
var msg = {
   message: "updateText",
   text: $(this).text()
};

top.frames["group_b.html"].postMessage(JSON.stringify(msg), '*');
```

**Frame 2**

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{ 
  if (event.data.message === "updateText"){
    $('#alltext').text(event.data.text);
  }
}
```

Note you'll have to place the code in places where the jQuery objects are in scope.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal html https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/shs21jgs/ your javascript code needs to close properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
        $('#alltext').append($(this).text());

        $("a").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
          });
          function redirectPage() {
              top.frames["group_b.html"].location = linkLocation;
          };
    });
});
```